# What kind of classical ciphers are there?

Tags: classical-cipher

I want a list of classical ciphers that can be used, I'm trying to find more classical ciphers online, but there isn't too much information, so, can someone list some more classical ciphers, and not the ordinary Caesar Cipher, Block Cipher,...

Comment: Block cipher is a classical cipher?

Comment: *`I want a list of classical ciphers...`* is a clear sign you have yet to  [check the information contained on the several pages of our help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help). Please do, as it prevents you from collecting down-votes and/or close-votes for posting off-topic questions. Besides that, keep in mind that doing some research on your own never hurts. At worst, it will help you narrow the scope of your questions - at best, it might even provide the answer(s) you might be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a website where you can find, study, and analyze several classical ciphers:

[Black Chamber](http://www.simonsingh.net/The_Black_Chamber/index.html)

The website includes several forms of classical ciphers apart from the ones you've asked an answer to omit.  A short list of those included in the link are:

- Pigpen Cipher
- Latin Square
- Vigenère cipher
- Homophonic Cipher
- Playfair Cipher
- Digraph Cipher

For a complete list of the ciphers on the site provided, follow this link:
[Black Chamber Guide](http://www.simonsingh.net/The_Black_Chamber/chamberguide.html)